# Multiple regression with categorical moderator (age) and continuous IV's and DV

Tags: regression, categorical-data, interaction

I am doing a multiple regression with 6 IV's, 1 DV, and 1 moderator.  I am having a problem trying to understand how to get the effect of the moderator which is age group (i.e. 18-25, 26-35, etc.).   I have dummy coded the age groups, but just not sure what to do to get the effect of age on the relationship between the IV's and DV.

I have found example after example, but only for 1 IV, 1 DV, and 1 moderator. I do understand these, but a little different when you have 6 IV's, 1 DV,  and 6 dummy coded age groups (k-1).

Comment: This obviously isn't a software-specific question, but for me it would help in my response to know what stat package you are working with; that way I could provide workable code for you to implement.

Comment: Do you mean you are not sure how to get a single p-value for the whole group of age variables?

Comment: I am using IBM SPSS with stepwise forward multiple regression. I am not sure how to correctly run analysis in SPSS for the effect of age (dummy coded categorical moderator variable).